# Exporting the value of radio button field from PDF to text

Tags: unix, pdf, formatting, pdftotext

In order to perform some natural language processing operations on a set of PDF files, I need to automatically extract the values of some radio button fields from an OCR scanned PDF file to text. When using pdftotext, a two choice radio button (Female, Male) is exported to text such as:

> Sex
>
> Female
>
> Male

What I need is some kind of annotation showing what radio button has been chosen, i.e. something like:

> Sex
>
> X Female
>
> Male

Is there a UNIX tool that can do this? I've read the manual to pdftotext and tried switches such as -raw and -layout with no success.

Thanks in advance.

**TL;DR Can I extract the value of a radio button from an OCR scanned PDF document with UNIX tools such as pdftotext or similar?**

Comment: can you provide a sample document?

Comment: I sure can. Here is a link to a sample document uploaded on Google Drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_W43jzXm1bNeVdJZXR6akx4YTg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: no success with pdftotext neither. if you find a solution please post your answer! goodluck.